# How to use shmat with non-NULL page-aligned shmaddr?

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to create shared memory with the address of heap-created variables, I ensured the address to be page-aligned, but still get the error: "Invalid argument". How could I correctly do this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <cstdint>
const int PERMISSION = 0666; //-rw-rw-rw-

int main() {
    int size = 10;
    void* testp = std::aligned_alloc(SHMLBA, size);
    int shkey = 314159, shmid;
    if ((shmid = shmget(shkey, size, IPC_CREAT | PERMISSION)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget: shmget failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    void *ret;
    if ((ret = shmat(shmid, testp, 0)) == (void*)-1) {
        perror("shmat: shmat failed");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++17 standard says as noted [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/aligned_alloc),

> Passing a `size` which is not an integral multiple of alignment or an
>   alignment which is not valid or not supported by the implementation
>   causes the function to fail and return a null pointer (C11, as
>   published, specified undefined behavior in this case, this was
>   corrected by DR 460).

So what is `SHMLBA`? It should be an integral that, as being said, a factor of the alignment.

Comment: Hi, `SHMLBA` here is the page size specified in `shm.h`, `shmat` requires the address passed in to be page-aligned. So should be fine.

Comment: @SiqiuYao Exactly it is not fine since, for example in Mac OSX,  `#define SHMLBA      4096`.  So, the fact that `SHMLBA` is defined in `shm.h` header doesn't necessarily satisfy the case I've already mention. `4096 % 10 != 0`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have to pass `SHM_REMAP` when calling `shmat` with a non-NULL argument:

```
shmat (shmid, testp, SHM_REMAP);
```

It is not immediately obvious why this should be.  According to the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat), this flag is Linux-specific.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HY0Wo08yrHBskHSu)